objects are deleted when rendering
I'm new to Blender, I have the following problem. When going to the rendering tab, the copied objects are deleted, leaving only the original. Would anyone know how to help me?

Make sure that the copies are visible for render in the Outliner, or if you use tools like Array modifier, make sure that the visibility for render is activated in the modifier

Thanks, they weren't visible

Make sure that the copies are visible for render in the Outliner, or if you use tools like Array modifier, make sure that the visibility for render is activated in the modifier.
